# Watson text to speech not working in Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I just started working with the java SDK for IBM's Watson TTS.  From a Spring app I can save .ogg and .wav files which play fine in Firefox and Audacity.  I can also play both files accessed from my website running on Firefox.  However neither one will play in Chrome.  I don't think it's Chrome itself because it will play .ogg files from other sources, both online and from a file.  Interestingly, the Watson demo also doesn't work in Chrome: https://text-to-speech-demo.mybluemix.net/.  Has anyone else run into this problem?  I'm using the latest version of the java SDK, 3.3.0.

**Update**

It appears it's a config issue of some sort. I tried the test .ogg file on my laptop and it worked fine, as did the TTS demo (should have done this earlier). My PC and laptop are running the exact same version of Chrome, both on Win10, and the settings look to be identical. I noticed that the sample that does work on my PC was a stereo file so I used Audacity to convert my test file to stereo and it worked!  Huh???  So, I'm stuck trying to figure out what's going on - is it a Chrome setting (unlikely) or a driver issue with my speakers? They are an old set of RealTek speakers that I've never had any issues with. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just checked, works in Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to waste anyone's time looking at this question. I played around with the speaker settings - it was set to 5.1 surround with 5 speakers and a subwoofer.  I only have 2 speakers and a subwoofer so I took out the other 3 speakers and the test file now works in Chrome as does the Watson TTS demo. Weird, though, that the speaker settings didn't affect Firefox. That's 5 wasted hours of frustration I'm never going to get back...

Comment: Turns out that since the Watson .ogg file is mono Chrome was trying to play it through the center speaker, which doesn't exist.